# Grouping/Formatting Data in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I am trying to show a group level data in a single column. Please find details below.

I have data in database in below format:

[image]

The above data can be grouped like below:

[image]

How can it be done like below in SSRS (grouping in a single column). Please let me know if its not clear.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the row groups for Master and Senior levels, you can delete the columns created for the groups without deleting the groups.

When you create the grouping, you can select Group Footer, when you do this should create a new row where you can then put the values for the grouping.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got it by doing groupings in table. Can it be possible by using Matrix.